# Generic Serverless Hub for SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, azure-signalr

SignalR has a Hub class that looks like this:

```cs
  public abstract class Hub<T> : Hub where T : class
  {
    protected Hub();
    public IHubCallerClients<T> Clients { get; set; }
  }

public interface IHubCallerClients : IHubCallerClients<IClientProxy>, IHubClients<IClientProxy>
```

Which uses a IClientProxy type so you can call interface methods instead of `SendAsync()` on Clients. I want to do the same thing with the `Serverless Hub` class which does not have a generic constructor so how could I accomplish this? I've tried just inheriting and hiding the base property like so:

```cs
public abstract class ServerlessHub<T> : ServerlessHub
      where T : class
  {
    protected ServerlessHub(IServiceHubContext hubContext = null, IServiceManager serviceManager = null)
      : base(hubContext, serviceManager)
    {
    }

    public new IHubClients<T> Clients { get; }
  }
```

but I get a null reference exception for Clients.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this isn't possible yet, see this issue on Github:
[Support strongly typed Hub Clients](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/issues/131)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it got me to snooping in signalR repos and I ended up making my own! I shared the code in that same issue